# Improving my F# implementation of newton's method to find the roots

Tags: f#

I implemented newton's method to find roots of a function. I'm wondering if i can optimize the code as make it more time and space efficient and visually enlightening. Here I used a mutable variable, but I'm wondering if we can do it without. Here is the question and the code that I wrote:
[image]

```
open System

let newton (f:(float->float),x0: float,tol:float, dx:float)=
    let mutable x=x0
    while Math.Abs (f x) >= tol do
        //compute derivative
        let fderivative = (f x+dx-f x)/dx
        x<-x-(f x)/fderivative
    x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to avoid mutation:

```
let newton (f: float -> float,x0,tol,dx)=
    let rec loop x =
        if abs (f x) < tol then x
        else
            let f' = (f x+dx-f x)/dx
            x - f x / f' |> loop
    loop x0
```